# Illegal Thread State Exception when starting new thread

Tags: java, swing

Trying to terminate a thread and then start a new one, however when I go to start the new thread after supposedly getting rid of the other, it throws an `IllegalThreadStateException`. Any help would be greatly appreciated as I am sort of new to the thread thing.Thanks.

```
public class Start_btn_Listener extends JButton implements ActionListener {
/*
 * ActionListener for the Start button in which starts the pendulum animation by creating a new thread.
 */

static volatile Thread p =new Thread(GUI.shm_panel);







@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    if(!GUI.GetRunning()){ // Determines whether a thread of Pendulum_Swing is already running.
    p.start();
    GUI.running = true;
    }
    else{
        JLabel message = new JLabel("Pendulum is already running");
        Object[] options = {"OK"};
        final JOptionPane pane = new JOptionPane(message, JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE, JOptionPane.OK_OPTION, null, options);
        JDialog dialog = pane.createDialog(GUI.shm_panel, "Running");
        message.requestFocus();
        dialog.setVisible(true);
         /*
          * Displays an error message when the Start button is clicked but the pendulum is still going.
          * Longer than usual to remove the focus border from the OK button as it always bugs me.
          */

    }

}
public static Thread GetThread(){
    return p;
}
}
```

Comment: You can't restart an existing Thread. You need to create a "new" Thread and then start that Thread.

Comment: `GetThread()` .. 1) Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) and use it consistently. 2) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Comment: So where would I create the new Thread?

Comment: `So where would I create the new Thread?` before you start it?

Comment: I tried the answer below and it does let me make a new thread, however the thread is meant to paint on a JPanel, which it isn't.

Comment: You can call `start()` on a thread instance ONLY once. Any subsequent attempts to call `start()` on the same thread instance will throw that `IllegalThreadStateException`. I suggest you use ExecutorService and submit your Runnables to that pool

Comment: Nvm, found that I wasn't reseting "shutdown" in the right place. It's all working now, thanks for the help. :)

Answer (score 0):

You are starting your p thread again like:

```
p.start();
```

on certain event. You can't start already started i.e. running or shutted thread.

You would need to do something like:

```
p =new Thread(GUI.shm_panel);
p.start();
```

Comment: When i do this where p.start() is the exception isn't thrown, but i can't see the new thread made